# Transform punctuations form half width to full width

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode

I have a sentence below:

> 我今天去买菜,买了一个西瓜,花了1.2元,买了一个土豆,花了3.78元。还买了一个无花果,花了45.89，怎么办呢?好贵呀!贵的我不知道再买什么了。

The punctuations in it are half width. How to change them to fullwidth, like the following:

> 我今天去买菜，买了一个西瓜，花了1.2元，买了一个土豆，花了3.78元。还买了一个无花果，花了45.89，怎么办呢？好贵呀！贵的我不知道再买什么了。

Some punctuations to consider (not exhaustive):

- , to ，
- ? to ？
- ! to ！
- "" to “”
- ; to ；

Comment: by punctuation you mean only ,?

Comment: all, like ,to， ?to？ !to！""to“” ;to；

Comment: just replace the `,` with `, `?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, define the CharacterSet from which you want to transform your characters. So if you want only punctuation, the set could be `CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters` or `CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted`.

Then map each character from this set to its HalfwidthFullwidth transformation.

#### Swift 3 and 4

```
extension String {
    func transformingHalfwidthFullwidth(from aSet: CharacterSet) -> String {
        return String(characters.map {
            if String($0).rangeOfCharacter(from: aSet) != nil {
                let string = NSMutableString(string: String($0))
                CFStringTransform(string, nil, kCFStringTransformFullwidthHalfwidth, true)
                return String(string).characters.first!
            } else {
                return $0
            }
        })
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
let string = ",?!\"\";abc012図書館 助け 足場が痛い 多くの涙"
let result = string.transformingHalfwidthFullwidth(from: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted)

// it prints: ，？！＂＂；abc012図書館　助け　足場が痛い　多くの涙
print(result)
```

#### Objective-C

```
@implementation NSString (HalfwidthFullwidth)
- (NSString *)transformingHalfwidthFullwidth:(nonnull NSCharacterSet *)aSet {
    NSUInteger len = self.length;
    unichar buffer[len + 1];
    [self getCharacters:buffer range:NSMakeRange(0, len)];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        unichar c = buffer[i];
        NSMutableString *s = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCharacters:&c length:1];
        NSRange r = [s rangeOfCharacterFromSet:aSet];
        if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
            CFStringTransform((CFMutableStringRef)s, nil, kCFStringTransformFullwidthHalfwidth, true);
            [s getCharacters:buffer + i range:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
        }
    }
    return [NSString stringWithCharacters:buffer length:len];
}
@end
```

#### Usage

```
NSString *string = @",?!\"\";abc012図書館 助け 足場が痛い 多くの涙";
NSString *result = [string transformingHalfwidthFullwidth:NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet.invertedSet];

// it prints: ，？！＂＂；abc012図書館　助け　足場が痛い　多くの涙
NSLog(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use CFStringTransform like :

Objective C :

```
NSString *string = @" ? \"\"!我今天去买菜,买了一个西瓜,花了1.2元,买了一个土豆,花了3.78元。还买了一个无花果,花了45.89，怎么办呢?好贵呀!贵的我不知道再买什么了";
    NSMutableString *convertedString = [string mutableCopy];
    CFStringTransform((CFMutableStringRef)convertedString, NULL, kCFStringTransformFullwidthHalfwidth, true);

    NSLog(@"%@",convertedString);
```

Swift 3.0 :

```
 let string = NSMutableString( string: " ? \"\"!我今天去买菜,买了一个西瓜,花了1.2元,买了一个土豆,花了3.78元。还买了一个无花果,花了45.89，怎么办呢?好贵呀!贵的我不知道再买什么了" )
        CFStringTransform( string, nil, kCFStringTransformFullwidthHalfwidth, true )

        print(string)
```

Comment: You've got `false` in the Obj-C and `true` in the Swift, one must surely be a typo?

Comment: It's work, perfect solve the punctuations half width to full width, but the number with become fullwidth too, 1.2 becomes １．２　3.78 becomes ３．７８, How can avoid number become fullwidth? just want punctuations, thanks very much.

Comment: Checking it for you .,.

Comment: @Cœur in this sentence is just has numbers, but if this sentence has many  characters like "abcdefgmnji", it will become "ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｍｎｊｉ", so... best is way is just transform punctuations, but I have no good idea...

Comment: @Tolecen Since this solution did not do what you wanted, why did you accept it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a much better solution now:

```
"Half width".applyingTransform(.fullwidthToHalfwidth, reverse: true) // Ｈａｌｆ　ｗｉｄｔｈ
```

Of course, you can do the opposite by using `reverse: false`

It also works as intended with your text which mixes both: the punctuation is correct.

> 我今天去买菜，买了一个西瓜，花了１．２元，买了一个土豆，花了３．７８元。还买了一个无花果，花了４５．８９，怎么办呢？好贵呀！贵的我不知道再买什么了

Note that this will also transform other symbols such as numerals. You'll want to mix  the range finding of  Cœur if this is not ok.